# Kubernetes: How to write livenessprobe and readinessprobe with Exec having pipe

Tags: kubernetes, pipe, exec, readinessprobe

I am adding liveness probe and readiness probe using Exec probe.
My config looks like this:

```
readinessProbe:
    exec:
      command: "/usr/bin/jps -l | grep QueueProcess"
    periodSeconds: 10 
    failureThreshold: 2
    successThreshold: 2
```

When the above one didn't work. I modified this and also tried:

```
readinessProbe:
     exec:
       command: ["/usr/bin/jps", "-l", "|", "grep","QueueProcess"]
     periodSeconds: 10 
     failureThreshold: 2
     successThreshold: 2
```

On running `kubectl describe pod`, got following output:

```
  Normal   Created           37s                  kubelet             Created container app1
  Normal   Started           37s                  kubelet             Started container app1
  Warning  Unhealthy         6s (x3 over 26s)     kubelet             Readiness probe failed: invalid argument count
usage: jps [-help]
       jps [-q] [-mlvV] [<hostid>]

Definitions:
    <hostid>:      <hostname>[:<port>]
```

I tried another application, where I am running `grpcurl` to call health check:

```
readinessProbe:
    exec:
      command: ["grpcurl", "-plaintext", "-protoset", "/app/HealthCheck.protoset", "localhost:8123", "service.HealthCheckService/GetHealthCheck","|", "jq", ".", "|","grep","200"]
    periodSeconds: 10 
    failureThreshold: 2
    successThreshold: 2
```

On running `kubectl describe pod` for this one, I got:

```
  Normal   Created           23s                kubelet             Created container app2
  Normal   Started           23s                kubelet             Started container app2
  Warning  Unhealthy         3s (x2 over 13s)   kubelet             Readiness probe failed: Too many arguments.
Try 'grpcurl -help' for more details.
```

Both of these are failing.
The question, how can I write an `Exec probe`, which has a pipe(or multiple pipe) in it?

I am using EKS v1.18.
(Both the above configs belong to different applications.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually use a shell, since that's a shell feature. `sh -c "foo | bar"` or whatever. Also remember that all the relevant commands need to be available in the target image.

So your YAML should look like this:

```yaml
readinessProbe:
     exec:
       command: ["sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/jps -l | grep QueueProcess"]
     periodSeconds: 10 
     failureThreshold: 2
     successThreshold: 2
```

Comment: Have added more information, can you have a look.

Comment: The array form is correct but, again, you need to use a shell if you want shell features. The command is run _literally_. `command: [sh, -c, "/usr/bin/jps -l | grep QueueProcess"]`